# Variable sin definir,

Tags: python, variables, fibonacci

Quería correr el siguiente código, pero me dice que la variable "esprimo", no está definida. ¿algún concejo?
El código:

```
a = 1
b = 2
for i in range(44):
    for j in range(2,b//2):
        if b%j ==0:
            esprimo= False
        else:
            esprimo= True
    if esprimo ==True:
        print(b, "es primo.")
    c = a+b
    a = b
    b= c
```

Este código sirve básicamente para buscar los primeros 10 primos en la serie de Fibonacci.

Comment: Afuera de tu bucle `for` pon `esprimo = None` y listo

Comment: Muchas gracias, Christian.

Comment: de nada, si tienes otra pregunta no dudes en hacerla, con gusto te ayudaremos

Comment: El problema es que, ya que comienzas con `b=2`, en la primera iteración del bucle exterior, el bucle interior `for j in range(2, b//2)` no se va a realizar, puesto que `b//2` sería 1 para ese caso y `range(2,1)` está vacío. Ya que ese bucle no se ejecuta, la variable `esprimo` no es asignada, pero sin embargo después la consultas con `if esprimo == True`. Una lógica más correcta sería hacer `esprimo=False` justo delante del bucle interno en j, y entonces si `b%j==0` haces `esprimo=True` y `break` (no necesitas seguir mirando, ya sabes que no es primo)

Answer (score 0):

El código se puede simplificar y optimizar, eliminando variables y comparaciones.

Primero, tan pronto encuentre un divisor, puedo salir del `for j` con un `break`. Si no se encuentra un divisor, entonces se ejecuta la sentencia `else:` del `for`. Esta sentencia `else` se ejecuta sólo cuando el `for` (o `while`) termina en forma normal.

Para avanzar los valores de `a` y `b` no necesito una variable intermedia, ya que puedo usar una asignación múltiples como

```
x, y, z = y + z, z + x, x + y
```

donde primero se calcula el lado derecho y después se realizan las asignaciones. En este ejemplo, el nuevo `x` recibe la `y + z` calculado con sus valores originales.

```
a = 1
b = 2
for i in range(44):
    for j in range(2, b // 2):
        if b % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(b, "es primo.")

    a, b = b, a + b
```

produce:

```
2 es primo.
3 es primo.
5 es primo.
13 es primo.
89 es primo.
233 es primo.
1597 es primo.
28657 es primo.
514229 es primo.
433494437 es primo.
```

Comment: Tengo una pregunta, Candu Moe; ¿Por que al escribir a, b = b, a +b, el código sí muestra los primeros 10 primos de la serie de fibonacci, pero al escribir:
a = b
b = a + b
solo muestra:
2 es primo.
4 es primo.?

Comment: @Siderius'Nuncius. La instrucción usada es la forma Pythonesca de intercambiar dos valores sin tener que recurrir a una tercera variable. Esto funcion porque primero se calculan todos los valores del lado derecho, y luego se hacen la asignaciones.